# Self syntax in python

Tags: python, class, oop

Whenever I'm defining a class which has a number of parameters I often find myself doing something like this

```
class myClass(object):
    def __init__(self,param1,param2,param3, ...):
         self.param1 = param1
         self.param2 = param2
         self.param3 = param3
 ...
```

My question is: is there a smarter, Pythonier way of doing this?

Thanks,
Alex.

Comment: Might be smart, but if you're passing more than six arguments your code can get pretty ugly!

Comment: What you're doing is most readable and Pythonic, IMO. Only in special circumstances would I use another option if there were a large number of attributes, for example.

Comment: If you're passing six arguments to a constructor and copy them into attributes without further processing, on a regular basis, you probably want to revisit your notion of a clean API and of good OOP style.

Comment: To be quite honest, my background is numerical analysis and statistical physics, so usually i'm writing some code I want to run multiple times or to have some access to internal workings but it should be self-contained and reusable. I wouldn't NEED to use OO, yet I thought I might learn something as well. When you have for example a thermodynamical system, you'd have as parameters size, temperature, interaction strength, magnetic field, and whatnot. Maybe a class to represent the sytem and its dynamics is actually a bad idea, then.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could accept a variable number of named arguments and automatically set them, like this:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs): # variable named arguments
        for k, v in kwargs.items():
           setattr(self, k, v) # set the value of self.k to v, same as self.k = v


test = MyClass(param1="param1", param2="param2")
print test.param1 # "param1"
```

[setattr documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr)

Comment: It's a bit convoluted, but it surely gets the job done. Problem is I'd probably have to check if the attribute has defined everytime I use it. Thanks, though!

Comment: Since this is in the constructor the object it self will not have the attributes at this time so a check is not required.

Comment: Another thing which you'll sometimes see is `self.__dict__.update(kwargs)`.  However I prefer this approach.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass your parameters as a `keyword arguments`: -

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
     self.args = kwargs
```

Then you will instantiate your class like this: -

```
myClassObj = MyClass(a=12, b="abc")
```

Then your `args` dict will contain those arguments as key-value pair: -

```
{'a':12, 'b':'abc'}
```

to access the attributes: -

```
myClassObj.args['a']
myClassObj.args['b']
```

You can also pass a combination of various arguments. There are 4 kinds of arguments you can have in any function: -

- Positional Argument
- Default Argument
- Non-Keyword Argument
- Keyword argument.

In that order only. So the typical syntax of a function declaration is: -

```
def func(positional_arg, default_arg, *nkwargs, **kwargs)
```

See [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#more-on-defining-functions) for more on defining functions.

Comment: Then I can reference self.a and self.b inside the class later on?

Comment: But this doesn't produce the desired result. There will be only one attribute `args`, not multiple attributes.

Comment: @AlexS.. No, `self.args` accesses the dictionary. And then to access each argument: - `self.args['a']`

Comment: @LevLevitsky.. YEah and since that attribute is a dictinary, it can store all those attributes in it, and then we can access it. See my edited post.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
def __init__(self,*args):
   _init_args = ('param1','param2','param3')
   if len(_init_args) != len(args):
      raise TypeError('__init__ takes {nargs} args'.format(nargs=len(_init_args)))
   for k,v in zip(_init_args,*args):
      setattr(self,k,v)
```

But I really don't think this is much better than your original solution or the solution posted by `sean`.  The advantage of this over `sean`'s answer is that the user doesn't need to know what the names of the attributes in your class are.  It behaves a little bit more like a function declared:

```
def __init__(self,arg1,arg2,arg3):
    ...
```

Although there are still differences.